# Using v-slot:body with v-checkbox row selector

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

When using v-slot:body with a v-checkbox for the row selection I am getting an unexpected behavior compared to a v-data-table without any v-slot:body.  When the "items" object changes all the checkboxes are "selected" in the v-slot:body.

What is different from my v-checkbox and the one used by the v-data-table without v-slot:body?  Is there a way to fix this while still using the body slot?

```html
<v-data-table
  v-model="selected"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  item-key="name"
  show-select
  dense
  hide-default-footer
  class="elevation-1"
>
  <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="d in items" :key="d.name">
        <td>
          <v-checkbox
            v-model="selected"
            :value="d"
            style="margin:0px;padding:0px"
            hide-details>
          </v-checkbox>
        </td>
        <td>{{ d.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.calories }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Reproduction:
https://codepen.io/Straktor/pen/gOGpoqJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First grab the `isSelected` and `select` functions from the body slot.

```html
<template v-slot:body="{ items, isSelected, select}">
```

If you check vuetify's `v-data-table` API slots section, you can notice that the `body` slot includes the isSelected and select methods. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots

[image: body slot preview]

Instead of individual `item` slot. In body's slot you need to pass the item to these functions. So, in order to work with your `v-checkbox`. Configure them this way. We start removing the `v-model` value you used since that is managed by the data table. Then we pass our item `d` the one you defined in your `v-for` to the selection functions.

```html
<v-checkbox
   :input-value="isSelected(d)"
   style="margin:0px;padding:0px"
   color="#535353"
   hide-details
   @click="select(d,!isSelected(d))"
>                   
</v-checkbox>
```

Here's your example codepen working properly: https://codepen.io/cmfc31/pen/VwMvYpy?editors=1010

Comment: Fantastic!! I've been looking for so long for a similar issue, this solution helped me a lot. Thanks @cmfc31

Comment: You got it! I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define `v-checkbox` input as multiple, to allow processing of the bound model accordingly.

```html
<v-checkbox
  v-model="selected"
  multiple
  :value="d" 
  style="margin:0px;padding:0px"
  hide-details></v-checkbox>
```

Comment: I added multiple.

When the "items" object changes all the checkboxes are "unselected" instead of "selected".  Similar issue.